# js carousel with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, carousel, serialscroll

spend soo much time trying to solve this, but here goes:

requirements:

- vertical list of items, in a div-container, structure div/ul/li
- user should be able to scroll through list, with smooth scrolling by hovering over the div, scrolling accelerates towards the top and bottom
- the scrolling is endless towards both ends (ie. at the end of the list, the list starts again, instead of changing the direction)
- list is dynamically generated via js
- on click the selected item moves to the center, on mouse out, item nearest center moves to center
- list items don't have a fixed height

after giving up on rolling my own solution...
i've tried jcarousel which can be persuaded to do all of those things except smooth scrolling. also, when clicking on an item near the end of the list [using scroll()] and current item is the first item, the list scrolls backwards all the way to the end instead of just scrolling to the next item.

next up jquery.serialscroll. got everything working, except endless scrolling, or rather, the bottom can be made to scroll endlessly (via absolute positioning of the list items in a relative ul) but i've no idea what to do about scrolling to the top.

while scrolling, it can be assumed that no new items are added.

without the requirement of smooth and variable/unpredictable scrolling speed, the problems don't seem too hard to solve, but all combined i just can't seem to find a solution.

is there a jquery plugin i've missed or has someone got it to work using serialscroll or jcarousel?

hope this is sufficient info and there's not too much lost in translation.

cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best one I've found is this one: http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

I believe it meets all (or certainly most) of your requirements, works on all browsers, and it doesn't even need JQuery.

Hope that helps.